# Login page not fully login out user iOS

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, xcode7, alamofire

So I have a login page where there are two view in one view controller. One of the views is the login page and the other view displays the user information. They are linked via login and logout buttons.
Once it log into the page it works fine. The problem is when I log off it goes back to the login page. But when I try to login with another user with out shutting down the simulator, the pervious user information is still there. I don't know if its a problem with my code or my set up. This is how the page is set up

UPDATE: It seems that the old json file does not get cleared at all until the phone is stopped and restarted. Once I do this the last user that was login will be displayed. So it is problem something with the download section. I am sending the right username and password but it never updates the UI in the user page.

and this is the majority of the code that is being use

```
//userNameInput:  passwordInput:

@IBAction func onLoginClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    myUserNAmeInput = TextFieldInput1.text!
    myPasswordUserInput = TextInput2.text!

    checkLoginCredentials(url)

}

@IBAction func onLogoutClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    //null out everything for logout
    theuserName = ""
    theUserPass = ""
     self.myJson = ""

    self.stored.setObject(self.userNAme, forKey: "uName")
    self.stored.setObject(self.userpassword, forKey: "uPass")
    self.stored.synchronize()
    self.view = myView
}

    func downlaodCI(myUrl : String, myUser : String, myPass : String)
    {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl)
        .authenticate(user: myUser, password: myPass)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString { response in
            //print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
            self.myJson = response.result.value!


    }
}
```

Thank you for any help with this

Comment: Could you post the code on how you show the login and logout pages? whether you use segue, push controller?

Comment: @ZhaoYi I do it like this self.view = MyPageView to show the user information and I use this self.view = LoginView to logout.

Comment: could you post the button action for login/logout as well?

Comment: I have posted the button actions above the new ones that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear out all the information on each fields like below:

```
userNameInput.text = ""
passwordInput.text = ""
```

Comment: From what I have seen in the log it just keeps using the same json file that it downloads the first time. Once I stop the app and restart it it will load the new user info no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the string values null when you press the logout button.
Example :- barcode.text ="" 
Like this try this code in your logout process.

Comment: Still the same issue. It keeps going back to the old user. I even check what I am sending to the server and it still pulling the old information. I nulled out the variable like you suggested. Seeing that its pulling the old into it has to be something with the sending or receiving part

Comment: Also do same for your json object. It will leads you the wrong input

Comment: I tried that too, I cleared it on logout, and I also cleared it right before I download a new one. Does Alamofire save data and reuse it?

Comment: Yes here is a example link for you.https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started